# How to show results of DDL statement (like Oracle does) in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: ssms

Is there a way to show the results of DDL statements such as `CREATE`/`ALTER`; after they are "run" in the query window?

By default it just shows "command(s) completed".

Is there a way to see something similar to the results Oracle shows from the same commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"command(s) completed" after a create table command is very similar to 'table created' oracle sql*plus message.

If you need a **desc my_table** you can execute **sp_help my_table**

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'll use. Appreciate the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Built-in?  No, not that I know of.  But you can easily do this with a `SELECT` to the respective catalog view to verify what you've just done.  Something like this would work:

```
create login SomeTestLogin with password = 'password'
go

select *
from sys.server_principals
where name = 'SomeTestLogin'
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **sp_helptext my_sp** for describe stored procedure, function, or view